# How to change 0.80 to 0.8 / 1.0 to 1 in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0.70,1.0,0.75,0.0,5.0], columns=['pitch'])
```

I want to convert it into

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0.7,1,0.75,0,5], columns=['pitch'])
```

If i convert the float to int, `0.7` will be 0 .

How to solve this problem, thanks!!

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the mechanism of data storage. There is no difference in Python between `0.8` and `0.80`. They're the same sequence of bits under the hood. If you want to change how they're *printed*, that's a formatting issue, not a data integrity issue.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo how to change the format?

Answer (score 0):

[astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
e    [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html)

can use the astype(int) function in conjunction with the round() function on the dataframe. This will round each value in the 'pitch' column to the desired number of decimal places and then convert those rounded values to integers.

```
df['pitch'] = df['pitch'].round(1).astype(int)
```

or using round(0) to remove decimal places completely

```
df['pitch'] = df['pitch'].round(0).astype(int)
```

Be careful using the astype(int) function to convert to int, as it can round values, not just remove decimal places.

Comment: But in this case, 0.70 would be 0 also 0.75 would be 0.

Comment: use `df['pitch'] = df['pitch'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.1f}")` **or** `df['pitch'] = df['pitch'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.1f}".rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if x % 1 != 0 else int(x))`

Comment: I think you are almost right!!!  But when i try 0.75, it will convert to 0.8. 0.7 in here is okay now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `round()` function to round the decimal values to the desired number of decimal places before converting them to integers. For example, you can use `round(df['pitch'], 1)` to round the values in the 'pitch' column to one decimal place, then use `astype(int)` to convert them to integers.

```
df['pitch'] = round(df['pitch'], 1).astype(int)
```

Comment: How to do this in multiple columns?

Comment: `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.round(1).astype(int))`